# ssh-agent plugin can't find credential specified as parameter

Tags: jenkins, ssh

In the `ssh-agent` credentials section of my jenkins job, I have two options:

- Specific credentials
- Parameter expression

My job works fine when I select `Specific credentials`, but when I choose `Parameter expression`, and fill in the value as ${CREDENTIAL_ID}, and run my job with parameter `CREDENTIAL_ID=<hex id of credential>`, the job dies with this trace:

> [WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
>   [WS-CLEANUP] Done
>   FATAL: 
>   java.io.IOException: [ssh-agent] Could not find specified credentials
>       at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshagent.SSHAgentBuildWrapper.preCheckout(SSHAgentBuildWrapper.java:204)
>       at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.preCheckout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:76)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:528)
>       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
>       at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
>   FATAL: [ssh-agent] Could not find specified credentials
>   java.io.IOException: [ssh-agent] Could not find specified credentials
>       at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshagent.SSHAgentBuildWrapper.preCheckout(SSHAgentBuildWrapper.java:204)
>       at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.preCheckout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:76)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:528)
>       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
>       at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
>   Finished: FAILURE

Any idea what might be going on? I'm running Jenkins ver. 1.654, Credentials Binding Plugin 1.6, SSH credentials plugin 1.11, and SSH agent plugin 1.9

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to achieve the same thing, using a *String Parameter* with the credential ID (the `hex value`, just like you posted in your problem's description).

The issue is that it seems that the *Parameter Expression* expects you to use a *Credential Parameter* instead of a *String Parameter*.

Although it's not exactly how you wanted to use it (you'll have to choose the key from a dropdown list when you trigger a build), changing the parameter type may be a suitable solution for you.